# operador ternario con varias condiciones js

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de colocar varias condiciones en un operador ternario en java script, pero no se como se podría hacer

hice esto pero pues esta mal, lo que quiero es que no se le ponga nada después de : en cada una de las condiciones  osea como si no tuviera else // si fuera  un if para cada una de las condiciones.

Gracias por la ayuda.

```js
    var notes = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese su calificacion"));
    
    
    if(!isNaN(notes)){
        notes >  7 ? alert("Ha aprobado"): notes < 4 ? alert("Ha desaprobado"): notes >= 4 && notes <= 6 ? alert("Tiene que recuperar");
        
    }else{
        alert("Por favor ingrse el valor en numeros")
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La clave para resolver situaciones como esta es organizar las comparaciones de modo que llegues a tener un valor por defecto.

Si en tu comparación inicial `notes >  7`, le indicas que compare si es *mayor **o igual** a 7*, ya tendrías cubierta una de las posibilidades. La segunda sería comparar si *es mayor o igual a 4 O menor o igual a 6*, o lo que es lo mismo, si el valor está entre 4 y 6. Si ninguna de las dos anteriores se cumple, asumirá entonces el valor por defecto o lo que es lo mismo, el valor será *menor que 4*. Pero esa evaluación no aparece, es la que se adquirirá **por defecto**.

Hagamos la prueba:

```js
var notes = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese su calificacion"));

if (!isNaN(notes)) {
  var msg =
    notes >= 7 ? "Ha aprobado" :
    notes >= 4 && notes <= 6 ? "Tiene que recuperar" :
    "Ha desaprobado";
  console.log(msg);
  alert(msg);

} else {
  alert("Por favor ingrse el valor en numeros")
}
```

Aplicando el mismo criterio, podemos centrarnos en evaluar en primer término si el valor *es menor que 4* o si *está entre 4 y 6*. Si ninguna de las dos ocurre, significa que *es mayor o igual a 7*. Pero esta evaluación no aparecerá de forma implícita, porque habrá pasado a ser la opción por defecto.

Veamos el ejemplo:

```js
var notes = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese su calificacion"));

if (!isNaN(notes)) {
  var msg =
    notes < 4 ? "Ha desaprobado" :
    notes >= 4 && notes <= 6 ? "Tiene que recuperar" :
    "Ha aprobado";
  console.log(msg);
  alert(msg);

} else {
  alert("Por favor ingrse el valor en numeros")
}
```

La clave es acotar las opciones, de modo que llegues a determinar de forma clara cuál sería la opción por defecto, a la cual se llegaría si ninguna de las anteriores se cumplen. En este tipo de evaluaciones conviene incluso *verbalizar*  lo que queremos para luego aplicarlo en código: *(a) si es mayor **o igual** a 7 quiero esto, (b) si está entre 4 y 6 quiero esto, (c) de lo contrario quiero esto*. En tu caso la confusión vino porque en (a) faltó aplicar el **o igual**, lo cual rompía la lógica, un simple signo de `=` estaba pues provocando que te perdieras en tu propia lógica :-) .