# ¿Por qué no funciona este operador ternario + callback?

Tags: javascript, condiciones

```js
function multiplicarArgumentos () {
 // Usa la palabra clave `arguments` para multiplicar todos los argumentos y devolver el producto
  // Si no se pasan argumentos devuelve 0. Si se pasa un argumento, simplemente devuélvelo
  // Escribe tu código aquí:

  return (arguments.length < 1) ? 0 : (arguments.length === 1) ? arguments[0];
}
```

Estoy tratando de hacer el operador ternario de esta solución que hice con un `if` común:

```js
if (arguments.length < 1) return 0;

else if (arguments.length === 1) return arguments[0];
```

Pero el editor me lanza un error diciendo que al final del último elemento falta algo (es decir, al final de `arguments[0]` salta la existencia de un error).

entonces armé este otro código completo, queriendo usar una callback:

```
function multiplicarArgumentos() {
  // Usa la palabra clave `arguments` para multiplicar todos los argumentos y devolver el producto
  // Si no se pasan argumentos devuelve 0. Si se pasa un argumento, simplemente devuélvelo
  // Escribe tu código aquí:
  let multiplicar = arguments[0];

  return (arguments.length < 1) ? 0 
  : (arguments.length === 1) ? arguments[0] 
  : cb();
  
 
  function cb(){
    for(let i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
    multiplicar *= arguments[i];
     } return multiplicar
  }
}
```

no sé como modificar ese operador ternario para que quede bien, la callback fue mi idea (y de paso trato de aprender este tema) pero no sé si está bien :( el error que me tira es:

multiplicarArgumentos() › should return the product of all the arguments

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: 25
Received: undefined

  115 |     const product4 = multiplicarArgumentos(1);
  116 |     const product5 = multiplicarArgumentos(10, 0, 10);
> 117 |     expect(product).toBe(25);
      |                     ^
  118 |     expect(product2).toBe(0);
  119 |     expect(product3).toBe(81);
  120 |     expect(product4).toBe(1);
```

Comment: creo que esto te podría ayudar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329880/operador-ternario-con-varias-condiciones-js

Comment: por lo que entendí te esta faltando un else en este caso (:) al final

Comment: ahí complete con el resto del codigo

Comment: El problema ahora es que la función `cb` está usando sus propios `arguments`, por lo que no le multiplica nada a la variable `multiplicar`

Comment: Gracias @OscarG !!!! para resolverlo pasé arguments a array en una variable y la usé para reemplazar arguments en cada lugar, y ya pude. Excelente tu aporte!

Comment: Recuerda dejar la pregunta como estuvo al inicio, y las ediciones, van como nueva pregunta, si tienes dudas puedes ir a la sala de chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol donde siempre hay buena vibra :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escenario actual:

```
return (arguments.length < 1) ? 0 : (arguments.length === 1) ? arguments[0];
```

Ordenando:

```
return (arguments.length < 1) ? 0 //Dentro del primer IF
                              : (arguments.length === 1) ? arguments[0]; // Aqui tiene un ELSE y dentr hay un IF, solo tiene una instrucción, falta :
```

Solución:

```
return (arguments.length < 1) ? 0 // ¿Se cumple la condición? -> CERO
                              // ¿No se cumple la condición -> Nueva condición 
                              : (arguments.length === 1) ? arguments[0] // ¿Se cumple este arguments.length === 1 ? -> usa arguments[0]
                                                         : // Aqui tiene que haber algo porque no se cumple arguments.length === 1
```

Comment: Hola, modifique el enunciado agregándole una parte final, pero me da error también, me ayudarías a pensarlo nuevamente?

Comment: Negativo. Lo ideal es dejar la pregunta como estuvo, marcar la respuesta como aceptada y después crear una nueva pregunta porque el escenario es totalmente diferente, ahora se trata de pruebas unitarias, nada que ver con operadores ternarios, y pues, así, hay mayor chance de obtener una buena respuesta. Saludos :D

Comment: Ahh no sabía, bueno muchas gracias!

Comment: Para servirles, recuerda darle click en el check verde de la izquierda, de ese modo aceptas la respuesta :)

Answer (score 0):

en mi caso utilizo return para salir del scope en caso de cumplir una condicion

```
if (arguments[0] == undefined) return 0;
  let resultado = 1;
  for (let index = 0; index <= arguments.length - 1; index++) {
    resultado = resultado * arguments[index];
  }
  return resultado;
```